# How do I switch between http and https in .htaccess?

Tags: http, .htaccess, https

I know this question has been asked several different ways and I've looked/tried many of the suggestions, but not getting anywhere.

I have a site that's mixed http and https where everything /customer and /cart including any subdirectories are https and the rest is http. I'm having a problem with it actually going to https, seems as though it goes to https and right back to http with this.

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule (.*) /public.php?debug=%{SERVER_NAME} [NS,QSA,L]

# Redirect to HTTPS if /cart or /customer
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cart.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customer.*
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

# go back to regular http if not in secure area
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cart.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customer.*
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

#simulate the static pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public.php?controller=index&action=index [L]

#Main rewrite for application/controller/action decode logic

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/scripts/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/css/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)$ /public.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/$ /public.php?controller=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)$ /$1/$2/ [QSA,L,R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /$1/ [QSA,L,R]

AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Maybe somebody can straighten me out on this.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the RewriteCond rules group together like an 'AND' rather than an 'OR' so the path would have to match 'cart' and 'customer' for the rewriterule to be applied (which wouldn't make sense). Try this..

```
# redirect non-https requests for /cart or /customer to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(cart|customer) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

# redirect all other https requests to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond $1 !^(cart|customer)
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this question for the similar issue
[htaccess (https to http)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818869/htaccess-https-to-http)

Even if you make it work, your page will be semi encrypted and browser will show a red mark at the status bar. You need to make use of http referrer in the conditions too.