# https and http combined .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

I've got the follow problem.

I have a website and for the directories /members and /admin I have a .htaccess which forces these URLs to go to https:// 
All other URLs are forced to go to normal https://

Now, for /members which is https:// I have in the pages a reference to /js/script.js which in imported into the page, but ofcourse this directory /js is forced to normal http:// while the page is displayed in https://

Internet Explorer users are shown a popup if they want to view non-secure content in the secure page, if they click yes, it's ok. If they click no, then the javascript doesn't work.

The /js is used in the normal http:// website and also in the /members secure website. This also is the case for the /images directory

So i'm not sure how to solve this problem. Other than say that /js and /images can be https or http. But I have no clue on how to configure this in the htaccess file.

Any help would be much appreciated!

This is the htaccess file I use now :

```
  #Turn SSL on everything, except members and admin
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(/members|/admin)
  RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  # Turn SSL off everything, except members and admin
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/members|/admin)
  RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few approaches. Here are just a few.

**Number 1.** Add this **before** your rules:

```
# do not do anything for js/css/image files
# (will affect ALL such files in ALL folders)
RewriteRule \.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png|ico)$ - [L]
```

The rule above will leave protocol as is for ALL css/js/image files (anywhere on a site)

**Number 2.** Add this **before** your rules:

```
# do not do anything to any files in css/js/images folders
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/ - [L]
```

The rule above will leave protocol as is for ALL files in css/js/image folders (e.g. `example.com/js/main.js`, `example.com/images/logo.png` or even `example.com/js/compress.php`

**If you want** -- you can combine them into single rule (to be more specific) -- but that is unnecessary (from my point of view).

Comment: Nice! This fixed my problem.
I even had a .css in the root folder (bad design...argh) so I added both the RewriteRules for the folder and file types. Me happy, thanks!!

Comment: @StevenFilipowicz You do not really need both if you have #1 as it will cover such files anywhere on your site (unless you have other file extensions in your css/js/images folders, e.g. .php).

Comment: Uuhhh yes you are right!
What does the option [L] do? Do you maybe have a good rewrite reference tutorial page? 
These rewrite rules are so powerful but I don't understand them and would love to create and understand these rules. Thanks again!

Comment: @StevenFilipowicz I do not know about any good tutorials -- I learned that using try-and-error approach plus some various examples from internet plus official documentation (has explanation for each directive and flags): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/

Answer (score 1):

In your images and js directories create their own .htacess file with the following in it:-

```
RewriteEngine off
```

This will turn off writes for all files in that folder.

In your html do not specify the domain on the links so do `/js/myscript.js` instead of `http://mydomain.com/js/myscript.js` this way it will just inherit the same protocol as the page they are viewing it on.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue an year back.  Was able to arrive at a conclusion on my own finally.

Check out my question and answer [htaccess (https to http)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818869/htaccess-https-to-http)

Comment: Thanks! I checked your question. But the solution LazyOne gave is a very simple but effective solution which worked in one go. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: skimmed through, hope you are not getting the broken ssl icon on the bottom or top of the browser !! If a ssl page contains content from non-ssl, generally that is displayed which doesn't look good/secure.