# Wordpress Marketpress forces all links to be https after visiting secure area

Tags: wordpress, redirect, ssl

I am using Marketpress with Wordpress on my site. Marketpress only protects necessary pages via SSL. If I am on a page that is protected, that is `https://`, and try to access a regular link (ie: `Home` or `About Us` it will try to force https in the URL thus giving me an untrusted error. How can I get rid of this functionality as I don't want my whole site protected ever, and especially after a user has visited a secured area.

EDIT: 1 quick solution I guess is to manually enter the links in the custom menu area, but that is a bad workaround I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following in my header.php file, and it works great:

```
if(is_page_template( 'template1.php' ) || is_page_template( 'template2.php')) {
$pg_use_ssl = "yes";
}

if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on" && $pg_use_ssl != "yes") { // Force NO ssl
header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
exit();
 }

if($pg_use_ssl == "yes" && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on") { 
header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
exit();
}
```

This will force https:// only on specific page templates, and force http:// on all other page templates.

Answer (score 1):

Once the browser has been redirected to https it will stay there whilst relative URL's are used. e.g.

```
/folder/folder/page.html
```

instead of:

```
http://site.com/folder/folder/page.html
```

Given that this behavior is embedded in WordPress, it wouldn't be especially helpful overall to try to change it.

Instead, the best I can think of is to add a rewrite rule to .htaccess that rewrites https addresses back to http except for those parts of the site that require https.

Perhaps this question will help: [htaccess (https to http)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818869/htaccess-https-to-http)

If not, try: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3507002.htm